# How to use ng-options in angular where Label and value are same

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create dropdown using ng-options, but at edit page its not working.

js file :

```
$scope.items = [
    {name:"Angular"},
    {name:"java script"},
    {name:"Css3"},
    {name:"Html5"},
];

$scope.name= "Css3";
```

html file :

```
<div class="form-group">Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="name" ng-options="a.name for a in items track by a.name" placeholder="Select Item"></select>
</div>
```

its working fine.
but I got selected value like this :

```
name:{
     name:"selectedValue"
}
```

but I want like this :

```
name:"selectedValue"
in $scope.selected after selected value from dropdown.
```

and I referred this [blog](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

after comparing @Satpal's demo and my output by inspect element and getting this :

> my output

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="name" ng-options="a.name as a.name for a in items" placeholder="Select Item">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Angular">Angular</option>
    <option value="1" label="java script">java script</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" label="Css3">Css3</option>
    <option value="3">Html5</option>
</select>
```

> Satpal's output:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="name" ng-options="a.name as a.name for a in items" placeholder="Select Item">
    <option value="0">Angular</option>
    <option value="1">java script</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Css3</option>
    <option value="3">Html5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and share the link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression of [ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> select as label for value in array

*Code*

```
a.name as a.name for a in items
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ddkjb596/)

Comment: I already try this, but its not working and I am not able to find exact problem.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar What is not working? It's working properly in fiddle.

Comment: Yes I also seen fiddle is working correctly, I added reason in question. Please read question again.

Comment: When I use **track by a.name** it works fine.
But bind object in object Like **name:{name:"selectedValue"}**

Comment: @gauravbhavsar, then its selecting the object. might this help I have taken different route http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/5gLddone/

Comment: @satpal, many thanks last fiddle is helpful.
**ng-options="name for name in names track by name"** this is added and working fine.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar no need to use `track by name`

Comment: @satpal, don't know what's a problem, but it seems like label is not bind on UI, but Object is bind properly. 
When I use map() function it provides me array of label instead of array of object, So when I use track by its bind label instead of object and its working for me.